# MySQL DB migration and Sync

Tags: mysql, database, migration, database-migration

I have a MySQL DB running in production. I want to replicate it to another server with no downtime and after replicating it I want them sync. If I do it through taking the DB dump and restore it to new server and then starting sync there are fair chances to loose some records. How should it be done with no downtime and with consistency?

Thanks

Comment: innodb or myisam? Are you already generating binary logs? How large a dataset?

Comment: its myisam, logs are not generated and size is ~60GB

Comment: If binary logging is not enabled, then you cannot do this without downtime. You will need to restart to enable the binary logs. I will try to respond with a more thorough answer later.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MySQL Database Replication](http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_database_replication).